# PyGoogleVoice API Raises TypeError when trying to login

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to mess with the pygooglevoice api and am trying to run the example call program on the documentation website:

```
from googlevoice import Voice
from googlevoice.util import input

voice = Voice()
voice.login()

outgoingNumber = input('Number to call: ')
forwardingNumber = input('Number to call from [optional]: ') or None

voice.call(outgoingNumber, forwardingNumber)

if input('Calling now... cancel?[y/N] ').lower() == 'y':
    voice.cancel(outgoingNumber, forwardingNumber)
```

I then get the following error when voice.login() tries to execute:

```
File "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\configparser.py", line 406, in _interpolate_some
    rawval = parser.get(section, option, raw=True, fallback=rest)
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'
```

I am currently using Python 3.5 on a Windows 10 machine.  I am also 90% sure I configured my .gvoice file properly in my user home directory.  I have the email, password, and forwardingnumber all written out in that file.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Am I using a deprecated API?

Answer (score 0):

I found a more recent version of the library here: https://github.com/pettazz/pygooglevoice
This did fix my configparser error but I am now encountering another problem of a different nature.  However my primary problem is fixed.

Comment: What is the "problem of a different nature" that you are encountering?

Comment: So it didn't actually fix the ConfigParser issue.  It instead created an import error which hid the configparser error.  I eventually fixed this by looking at the issues on GitHub.  However I've pretty much given up on this for now because the module is incredibly broken and out of date.  I currently do not have the time to contribute to fixing it.